# conditional probabilites - pairs of balls

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Been struggling with an exercise for quite some time as i can't get the correct answer, so decided to get some help.

there are 8 black and 8 white balls in the urn. we randomly pull 4 balls in a row. let’s mark the events:

- A1 - (1-2 ball pair contains at least 1 white ball)
- A2 - (2-3 ball pair contains at least 1 black ball)
- A3 - (3-4 ball pair are both black)

simplify events $A = \neg(\neg A_1∪A_2)∩A_3$ and find probability $P(A)$.

what I did is first of all simplify the above event:

$A1∩\neg A2∩A3$

and try to calculate the events

$A1= \frac{8}{16}*\frac{7}{15}+\frac{8}{16}*\frac{8}{15}+\frac{8}{16}*\frac{8}{15}$
which is the same as $1-\frac{8}{16}*\frac{7}{15}$

so I did the same with the rest

$A2 = 1-\frac{8}{16}*\frac{7}{15}$

$A3 = \frac{1}{16}*\frac{7}{15}$

but in the end i couldn't get the right answer...
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you please explain if you have to meet all $3$ conditions $A1$, $A2$, $A3$ simultaneously? In other words, are they $3$ different problems or $1$ single problem where all $A1$, $A2$ and $A3$ need to be met?

Comment: i have to meet A1∩¬A2∩A3, it is a 1 single problem where all conditions need to be met

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken, but it looks like (not $A_2$) and $A_3$ are mutually exclusive (i.e. they can't both happen).  If I'm right, either you have a typo or the problem is meaningless or you are supposed to realize this and declare the probability = 0.

Comment: If event $A_2$ does not occur, then both the second and third balls must be white.  If event $A_3$ does occur, then both the third and fourth balls must be black.  Since the third ball cannot be both black and white,  $A_2' \cap A_3 = \emptyset \implies A_1 \cap A_2' \cap A_3 = \emptyset$, where $A_2'$ is the event that $A_2$ does not occur.

Comment: it surely seems like it, unless i simplified it incorrectly, but that doesn't seem like it is the case, thank you all for help

Comment: your simplification seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answered by the comments and sadly i can't mark them as answers

> Perhaps I am mistaken, but it looks like (not A2) and A3 are mutually
> exclusive (i.e. they can't both happen). If I'm right, either you have
> a typo or the problem is meaningless or you are supposed to realize
> this and declare the probability = 0.